# How to pass sql query data onto the datasets field of chartjs using nodejs (ejs)

Tags: node.js, chart.js, ejs

I'm trying to create a bar graph that takes the output of my SQL query that I'm passing from the main function.

In the body tag I can get this by

```
<Body>
<%=query[0].ColName %>
</Body>
```

However I'm not able to pass onto my script tag for creating a bar chart.

I tried the following code which didn't work.

```
<Script>


var out1= query1[0].ColName;

var out2= query2[0].ColName;

var out3= query3[0].ColName;



var chart = new Chart(,{

type : 'bar',

data : {
labels :

*data: [out1,out2,out3]*
}]
```

Note : This is a sample code and not the main code. Need help in passing the 'out' variables onto the data array of the bar chart. Running this code as part of a ejs file.

Answer (score 0):

Access query variable in JavaScript like this and use it in chart.js.

```
<script>
  var data = <%= query %>    
</script>
```

Comment: I had tried this and it doesn't work as my query runs in another main.js file from where I fetch the data. Also, I cannot pass your code in my ejs file without a error.